# How to get a thumbnail of a live stream?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming, mediametadataretriever

I am currently using `MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime` on Android to get thumbnails of videos and it is working great except for live streams (m3u8). Using the m3u8 directly doesn't seem to work and I have managed to get a bitmap back for a `.ts` segment file using that same method but it is always just a black bitmap. So how can I get a thumbnail of a live stream?

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, since the `m3u8` is a live stream, what is the motivation to create a thumbnail? Do you plan to store the same into the disk?

Comment: Just to show it on the list. I already show thumbnails for other videos and that is just the easiest way to make it look consistent. I also saw an iptv app that did that and it didn't look half bad.

Comment: Ok. Have you considered storing the incoming data into a temporary file and then running `MediaMetadataRetriever` on the same?

Comment: Yeah but if that is the only way then I don't really want to go down the thumbnail route. Those playlists of live stream channels can be huge.

Comment: Well.. You don't have to download the entire stream. Maybe the first one or five seconds should be sufficient right, which shouldn't be too large

Comment: I'll try it out but I'm not sure why it would make a difference. I already tried using one of the .ts segments and MediaMetadataRetriever works fine with network streams.